# Counting occurrences by group

Tags: text-processing, awk

Counting how many zeros exists in the 3rd column, per group in the first column.
E.g.

```
A   1   0 
A   2   0 
A   3   2 
B   1   2
```

Desired output:

```
A 2
B 0
```

Something like:

```
cat input | awk '{if($3>0) total+=1}END{print total}'
```

but for every distinct $1 group

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use an associative array in `awk` to count the occurrences of zeros for each group:

```
awk '$3 == 0 && ++count[$1] || count[$1] { next } END { for (group in count) printf("%s%s%d\n", group, OFS, count[group]) }' file
```

The slightly awkward

```awk
$3 == 0 && ++count[$1] || count[$1] { next }
```

will test to see whether the third column is zero and if so, increment the counter for that group. If it isn't, it still instantiates an empty element for that group in the `count` array.  We need this to be able to report groups with zero zeros at the end.  The `next` is just for skipping to the next input line.

muru points out in comments that this bit could be replaced by the slightly shorter

```awk
{ count[$1] += ($3 == 0) }
```

where `$3 == 0` will be either 0 or 1 depending on the value in the third column.

The output at the end is done with `printf()`:

```awk
printf("%s%s%d\n", group, OFS, count[group])
```

This would print the group (from the first column of the input data) together with the corresponding count of zeros, with `OFS` (the output field separator; by default a space character) in-between.

If the count is missing for one group, the `printf()` format `%d` will insert a zero.

Testing:

```
$ awk '$3 == 0 && ++count[$1] || count[$1] { next } END { for (group in count) printf("%s%s%d\n", group, OFS, count[group]) }' file
A 2
B 0
```

Comment: Since `$3 == 0` will be 1 or 0, that could be condensed to `'{count[$1] += $3 == 0} END {for ...`

Comment: @muru Yes, that look neater.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `awk '{if(!seen[$1]++){print $1}}' p.txt`; do re=`awk -v i="$i" '$1 == i && $3 == "0" {print i,NR}' p.txt|wc -l`; echo "$i $re"; done
```

output

```
A 2
B 0
```

Comment: No. You'd never loop this way in awk just as you'll never loop like `for i in $(cat file)`..

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{

##use key-value array in awk
if($1 in STORE){
    if($3 ==0){
        STORE[$1]+=1
    } ##if ends for 3rd column check

} ##if ends for A/B check
else{
    if($3 ==0){
        ##check if third column is zero
        STORE[$1]=1
    }else{
        ##if not zero, make value as zero
        STORE[$1]=0
    }

} ##else if A/B not in Store

}
END{
##print everything using for loop

for(key in STORE){
    print key, STORE[key]
}
}  ' file.txt
```